# How to set a type to be a string but not allowing some specific values?

Tags: typescript

I commonly use type aliases to restrict possible string values :

```
type MyType = 'string1' | 'string2' | 'string3';
```

This is handful in switch statements to do specific job depending on this value.

However, is it possible to have a type that is **Not** of this strings ?

Here's a [live sample of what I'm trying to achieve](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Basically, I get data from an api. The data contains several mixed items with a `type` attribute that define what kind of data the item consists in.

```js
// Get data from an API
const data: Contact[] = [
  {
    type: 'customer', accountId: 42, email: 'bill@corp.bzh'
  },
  {
    type: 'supplier', deliveryArea: 'Europe', email: 'support@corp.com'
  },
  {
    type: 'AnotherTypeOfContact', email: 'rene@lataupe.com'
  }
];
```

Which I map to

```
type ContactBase = {
  email: string;
}

type Customer = ContactBase & {
  type: 'customer';
  accountId: number;
}

type Supplier = ContactBase & {
  type: 'supplier';
  deliveryArea: 'Europe'
}

type BasicContact = ContactBase & {
  type: string; // Should be any other value than the one set before
}

type Contact = Customer | Supplier | BasicContact;
```

I want to iterate over the data and apply a specific behavior for certain types (but not all), and fallback to a simple behavior for others.

However, this does not compiles.

Here's what I tried:

```
// Loop over data, do something specific for well known types and fallback for others
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const item = data[i];

  switch (item.type) {
    case 'supplier':
      console.log(`${item.email} is a supplier which ships in ${item.deliveryArea}`);
      break;
    case 'customer':
      console.log(`${item.email} is a customer with account id ${item.accountId}`);
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`${item.email} is a contact of type ${item.type}`)
      break;
  }
}
```

As soon as every well known type has a dedicated `case` statement, it stops to compiles.

If I remove the `type` from the `BasicContact` type, it does not compiles.

I also tried to exclude string using `type: Exclude<string, 'customer' | 'supplier'>`, but it still does not compile.

How to fix ?

Comment: Why the unconventional naming with lowerPascalCase types?  Could you modify them to be UpperPascalCase so as not to distract from your issue?

Comment: naming changed.

Comment: TS doesn't currently have *negated types* so there's no specific type in TypeScript that works the way you want.  See [ms/TS#48073](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48073).  There may be workarounds but I don't know if you'd like any of them.  Should I write up the above as an answer, or are you specifically looking for workarounds?

Comment: You could try to make `Contact` generic to simulate negated types, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKyeZN) maybe?  Should I keep looking for workarounds?

Comment: thanks @jcalz. Let me try TJ's suggestion first, looks simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exclude specific string literals from the `string` type. (It would be cool, but you can't [edit: at least, [not yet](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48073), thanks as always [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)!]. :-) )

Instead, you could define your `Contact` type like this:

```typescript
type SpecificContact = Customer | Supplier;
type Contact = SpecificContact | BasicContact;
```

Then have a type predicate that tells you whether a contact is a specific or general type:

```typescript
function isSpecificContact(contact: Contact): contact is SpecificContact {
    return contact.type === "supplier" || contact.type === "customer";
}
```

Then the loop can branch depending on whether it's a specific type of contact:

```typescript
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data[i];

    if (isSpecificContact(item)) {
        switch (item.type) {
            case "supplier":
                console.log(`${item.email} is a supplier which ships in ${item.deliveryArea}`);
                break;
            case "customer":
                console.log(`${item.email} is a customer with account id ${item.accountId}`);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`${item.email} is a contact of type ${item.type}`);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwMbAELIM7QLxQDeAUFGVBALbICWANgFxTbABONCA5gNzEC+vYqEiwAriziUIrKAXhI0mHNABkRUuWEQmAIlTjgk6Tt7koaVHFFIAkgBMmCUZQBG03gOJDw0AMqiwMDoaaVlYRBR0LFwoNRIzLV1sAKCQ1hMNMjsIYIA3aRAAQVYIZF0AUVFWOEgMz28RaJpUeUjgMNbFaNV1BJ8mFnYubigAelGoXwALKzo7KDdzBBAoOGAp0NzkOlFodeQEKHXoRGhcdrcAMzgS-kEtSchUGkvmzvQOgyMZAB9JlOC7ga0He7QIvieLzeEUUUD+TRaMPQgksCBYUDsyBQTFBAG0ALphXGZXpmTT9KB6L5SdIAGhJZgsVlsDigABYAEz0snkKi0RiUlz0OgAAUsrDAADoXAAvKY6bnkPiKsjxHlHCk6ZKBQF0hnkbJ5ArFUoVKo1CAK-VkPn0JIpG7AMU3KWWShWszKklqnmJSmFBBrDasAAqPgA8pdQR71baBToSggICK6FjkAEIJK3TGyF78YJLtZ0DREFAaNgIRBnq9EQp0AAKVFtHFI4AASiYTdh5ceVahtbapLIJWAVUOXfQkoeeBnlO1qWMcL+E+AU58slnVIkNLqXnGUAAMnAaqt8jJMShaRi4MwjOsOJxmJCa1BrjIAO45OhQADWgffhxaNgSzzJc2x0C4aA-q+NyrMcrDYMQb5QPWdAQO0NBhAADCMmEADwYmmkpoVw6y4QA1ORbZDlAqLojQwBUGEF7ILiND5l4ZgvCh5aVtW0J1sA9YMVQbbUT6ZLYO+DGoFMPGMZQa6QOJ1pkqgyhzgCaQ6AwqnqrRiDYHAaHEXAnD1gABgAJIQImKXGfBlsByDMFpoTvlMzRydgnlgMBHBQDZdmSoaNBnkUJTIHwFltqY+nqi4kU-nF8W0RpW6GDuumpTydHGZmdBmZZQUKZKDlOeYtHUu5DFyUy1gYfMJVUJK9UstFsV6QlSUpWSfAko5OQxBJZh5SZhXmdZtmleVPYuSuqyXBqIjNYpWgdb1-V8EAA)

---

I don't like repeating strings as I have to in the type predicate above. To avoid that, you could have this constant object:

```typescript
const ContactTypes = {
    customer: "customer",
    supplier: "supplier",
} as const;
```

Then the types look like this:

```typescript
type Customer = ContactBase & {
    type: typeof ContactTypes.customer,
    accountId: number;
};
```

and the type predicate doesn't repeat strings:

```typescript
function isSpecificContact(contact: Contact): contact is SpecificContact {
    return contact.type in ContactTypes;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwuKBDYUAqBPADgUwjAXhgG8AoGCmYAV2hAFscAnALhgCIa7Gn2AacpQjUsWADYBLZm3bDRk5v1IBfGEnyhIUANylSUbDniIUUAELqjRMpRg56SCWLbQmEsAHNdy3fsPxaKAZmQmMwZFQLCCMAMhJBCgNcNiScEAAzMIj0QwgAOi4gngFbFFBqcIBJABM2MGp6ACNmb19UmABlEXEpJlCEcNMo2PjbVJTDDKzTTFx8uR6WhJhqnEkAN2YMAEEmHCQZAFFqJhBcdla9dqiJYAHs-pNIyxg4m0pxmFd3LxgAej+nQAFiBqGJqjBmmowBgYCAoECQuskGJqEYEUgwDAEUZwEZorBmukQHsVG1-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-Zas25RllUNYmuMzzIG6vyApCsLBqdaLFxG+9YCmdpFty1J1rqih9v2oA)

You can even use them in the loop (see the `***` lines), though repeating ourselves there is less of an issue because that'll be checked by the compiler, so it may be a bit overboard:

```typescript
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data[i];

    if (isSpecificContact(item)) {
        switch (item.type) {
            case ContactTypes.supplier: // ***
                console.log(`${item.email} is a supplier which ships in ${item.deliveryArea}`);
                break;
            case ContactTypes.customer: // ***
                console.log(`${item.email} is a customer with account id ${item.accountId}`);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`${item.email} is a contact of type ${item.type}`);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwuKBDYUAqBPADgUwjAXhgG8AoGCmYAV2hAFscAnALhgCIa7Gn2AacpQjUsWADYBLZm3bDRk5v1IBfGEnyhIUANylSUbDniIUUAELqjRMpRg56SCWLbQmEsAHNdy3fsPxaKAZmQmMwZFQLCCMAMhJBCgNcNiScEAAzMIj0QwgAOi4gngFbFFBqcIBJABM2MGp6ACNmb19UmABlEXEpJlCEcNMo2PjbVJTDDKzTTFx8uR6WhJhqnEkAN2YMAEEmHCQZAFFqJhBcdla9dqiJYAHs-pNIyxg4m0pxmFd3LxgAej+nQAFiBqGJqjBmmowBgYCAoECQuskGJqEYEUgwDAEUZwEZorBmukQHsVG1-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-NHMRApC3LrJiuLcKoTrkr0yyzQqJiIRGqK5otcrKs86rav2eqNuUZZVDWFrjO8yB+oCoKwoi0anVixcJvvWApnaJb8tSNaGooPa9qAA)

Comment: It will requires a bit of work to apply to my actual case (too complex to post as is). But this sounds very promising, I'll check

Comment: @SteveB - FWIW, I added a bit to reduce the amount of repetition. :-) And added playground links (I normally do that before post, but seem to have forgotten). Happy coding!

Comment: Here's the updated code, which works like a charm : https://tsplay.dev/WJyjkm